# FormData в объект DTO Spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rest, dto

Есть такое `DTO`:

```
public class OwnerProfileUpdateDTO {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phone;

    private String company;

    private long countryId;
    private long regionId;
    private long townId;

    private MultipartFile avatar;

    public OwnerProfileUpdateDTO() {}

    // getters and setters

}
```

Есть `REST` контроллер:

```
@RestController
@Secured("OWNER")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/owner",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ApiOwnerController {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerService ownerService;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(ApiOwnerController.class);

    @PostMapping(value = "/profile/update", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Response fillUpdate(Response response, OwnerProfileUpdateDTO ownerProfileUpdateDTO) {
        LOGGER.info(ownerProfileUpdateDTO);
        response.setSuccess("OK");
        return response;
    }

}
```

Отправляю данные на сервер в формате `FormData` при помощи `AJAX`:

```
$.ajax({
       url: 'update',
       data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
       type: 'POST',
       dataType: 'json',
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
})
```

Мне нужно передать файл и дополнительные данные, поэтому использую `FormData`
Но в `ownerProfileUpdateDTO` все поля все `null`. почему так? не могу понять.

Пробовал к `OwnerProfileUpdateDTO ownerProfileUpdateDTO` добавлять аннотацию `@RequestBody`, но при запросе выдает ошибку:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0iIfmbRKA2DP0lnF;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

что не так? как правильно сделать?

Comment: Получается, передаётся json-объект, составной частью которого является файл?

Comment: @МаксатОрунханов это не `json`. Данные передаются в формате `multipart/form-data`, а сервер мапит все параметры в мой объект. Если посмотрите в инспекторе браузера на вкладке `Network` на запрос, увидите в каком формате передаются данные.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае оказалось все так:

Добавил:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

и это:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

ну и в самом контроллере добавил `@ModelAttribute`:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/profile/update", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Response fillUpdate(Response response, @ModelAttribute 
 OwnerProfileUpdateDTO ownerProfileUpdateDTO) {
        LOGGER.info(ownerProfileUpdateDTO);
        response.setSuccess("OK");
        return response;
    }
```